# Does "The amount of consumption of total fruit of a human in one year" have multiple meanings?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I put the words of phrases below in parantheses to understand what modifies what. I also want to ask If there are more than one meaning?

> {(The amount) (of consumption of total fruit)} of {a human} in one year

What I learn is If there are different meaning for example if I use "cell" instead of "fruit" in sentence like

> {(The amount) (of consumption)} of {cell of a human} in one year

Structure will appear the same but Words that are modified by "of" will change. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The two sentences you posted do not appear to be the same. You included an additional "of" in the second one, between "total" and "cell".

Comment: Your sentence is not idiomatic. It would be more natural to say "The total amount of fruit consumed by a human in one year" or "The total consumption of fruit..." Also, what do you mean by _consumption of cell_?

Comment: [corrections: I also want, not wanting//Total fruit consumption//What I learned or am learning//if there are different meanings, with an s//The structure will appear the same]. As Kate says, your sentence makes little sense.

Answer (score -1):

In your example sentences

> {(The amount) (of consumption of total fruit)} of {a human} in one year

is about the consumption by a human whereas

> {(The amount) (of consumption)} of {cell of a human} in one year

is about the consumption by a **cell** *of a human* since the phrase *of a human* modifies **cell**.